# Why deserializing JSON gives 0 to each value

Tags: swift, swift3, alamofire

I am using `Alamofire` for GET request - it gives me status code 200 and the results are good, but after i deserialize the json into the array and then i try to sign the values into the custom object then it gives me always 0.

The json looks like :

```
{
  "user" : [
    {
      "name" : "Jack",
      "lastname" : Sparrow
    },
    {
      "name" : "John",
      "lastname" : Smith
    }
   ],
   "count" : 2
}
```

Then in my model i do have properties `name` and `lastname` with `init(name: String, lastname: String) { self.name = name self.lastname = lastname }`

The `GET` request looks like :

```
 Alamofire.request(BREADCRAMB_URL, method: .get, parameters: parameters).responseJSON { response in

            print("Get default graph request \(response.request!)")
            print("Get default graph response \(response.response!)")

            guard response.result.value != nil else {
                completion(nil, 0)
                return
            }
            var objects: [User] = []
            let jsonArray = JSON(data: response.data!)
            let count = jsonArray["count"].intValue
            print(jsonArray.count)
            for(_ , dict) in jsonArray {
                print(dict.count)
                let thisObject = User.init(name: dict["name"].stringValue, lastname: dict["lastname"].stringValue)
                print(thisObject)
                objects.append(thisObject)
            }
            completion(objects, count)
            print(objects.count)
            for o in objects {
                print(o.name)
                print(o.lastname)
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Because the JSON you gave is a Dictionary, not an array at toplevel? `let jsonDict = JSON(data: response.data!); let jsonUserArray = jsonDict["user"]; //then do you for loop with jsonUserArray`

Answer (score 0):

Use [AlamofireObjectMapper](https://github.com/tristanhimmelman/AlamofireObjectMapper) library. It makes easy to map object.

// Inside ViewController

```
var objects = [User]()

var serverResponse : ServerResponce

private func downloadMainViewData(){

        let params = ["":""]

        Alamofire.request(serverUrl, method: .get, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
            .responseObject{ (response: DataResponse<ServerResponse>) in

                self.serverResponse = response.result.value

                if(self.serverResponse != nil){
                    self.objects = (response.result.value?.slideShow)!
                }

        }

    }
```

// Class ServerResponce

```
    import ObjectMapper

    class ServerResponse : Mappable{

        var slideShow : [Show]?


        required init?(map: Map) {

        }

        func mapping(map: Map) {

            objects <- map["user"]


        }

    }
```

//  Class user

```
import ObjectMapper

class Uesr: Mappable{

    var name : String?
    var lastName : String?

    required init(map: Map){

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

        let transform = TransformOf<Int, String>(fromJSON: { (value: String?) -> Int? in
            // transform value from String? to Int?
            return Int(value!)
        }, toJSON: { (value: Int?) -> String? in
            // transform value from Int? to String?
            if let value = value {
                return String(value)
            }
            return nil
        })

        name <- map["name"]
        lastName <- map["lastname"]

    }
}
```